# Silverlight analog in Java environment

Tags: java, client-server

Is there any analog to Microsoft Silverlight in Java World? The requirement is to use native language and share some already written libraries while hosting in a web browser on client side. Silverlight is a great technology, but it doesn't work on Linux. Please don't remind me of Moonlight. Please don't suggest ActionScript as it's not Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[JavaFX](http://javafx.com/) springs immediately to mind, which sort of hangs around in the Flash/Silverlight space.  It's pretty immature, though, and not heavily used.

For a more general RCP platform, try [Eclipse RCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform).

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) or [Echo2](http://echo.nextapp.com/site/echo2)

You may find this review http://vinaytechs.blogspot.com/2009/09/comparison-matrix-of-ajax-frameworks-zk.html interesting as it covers many other options and lists the different features of each.